# How to model a dimension table that link to several facts with different level of grain?

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema, fact

I have a fact that store client's address. Problem is, the client can choose to insert information at state level, or county level, or street level. In the operation database, there is 1 table for streets, link to another table for counties, link to another table for states. The client table has 1 column for state, 1 column for county, 1 column for street that contain ID (so can link to higher object in the hierarchy)
How can I model the relationship between the fact and the dimension in a star-schema?

So I created one Location dimension with all states, all counties, all streets. The table look like this:

```
DIM_ID  | Level     | Street columns        | County columns        | State columns
1       | Street    | Bolsa                 | Westminton            | California
2       | County    | Westminton [county]   | Westminton            | California
3       | State     | [State of] California | [State of] California | California
```

If client disclose street then fact record link to row 1, client disclose county level then fact record link to row 2, client disclose only state then fact record link to row 3.

What do you think of that approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably model these levels separately, as they are being treated as separate, i.e.:

- dim.Street
- dim.County
- dim.State

As for relating these to clients, I'd go for bridge tables, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE ClientStreet
(
    ClientID
    , StreetID
)
```

Etc.

And if you cannot provide a Street without providing a County and State, or provide a County without providing a State, I would have within dim.Street, CountyID, and within dim.County, StateID, i.e. a hierarchical structure.

**EDIT**

With regards to your client dimensions with 3 IDs, this could also be a good model.

With regards to my hierarchical structure, and data modelling in general, I feel the way you model it really needs to:

1. Reflect reality (e.g., recording a client's Street as "[State of] California" seems inaccurate to me).
2. Reflect the reality of what is possible in terms of incoming data, i.e. do your clients input their address once, or can they change it (do you want to track changes?)?

One thing I'm wondering is if whether your clients have to pick one and only one of these levels to record their address at. In this case, I'd have either the model I'd suggested above, or I'd have client dimension with 3 IDs, and a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to ensure that only one of these was ever populated. This would then be supported be the fact that a Street would have a CountyID, etc. So you would determine this kind of "channel" by which ID is populated in the client dimension.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I should add that the client table has 1 column for state, 1 column for county, 1 column for street that all contain IDs (so can link to higher object in the hierarchy), so fitting the hierarchical structure you proposed. Can you specify more about that approach?

Comment: To be honest that sounds fine to me, a client dimension that has an ID for various address components. If that's how it's set up, I'm not sure why you'd need a Location dimension. For a client that only provides a state, for example, I'd just have the other two IDs as `NULL`. Let me add some more explanation.